# Free historical weather data API

Tags: meteorology, rainfall, python

Where can I find a free Python API that provides historical weather data (temperature, rainfall)? I'd need data of an Italian city, at least with hourly granularity.

Comment: How far back? I know of at least one dataset that goes back to 1980. This particular dataset doesn't have a specific Python API, but there are Python modules that will let you access it (given that you get a login) with relative ease.

Comment: Just few months back, but I need data about Italian locations

Comment: What Italian location are you looking for?

Comment: I would also like to get that data, especially if it's in a .csv format (or similar) where I can use the Python package called Pandas to access and manipulate it. If you find a link, please post it here.

Comment: Are you looking for raw station data or would climate reanalysis be an option for you?

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, perhaps try our sister site [opendata.se].